# Read and show json data live/Update every minute

Tags: python, json, dataframe, live, xlwings

My code reads json file from some link and turns it into pandas dataframe and saves it into csv file. Is there any way I can view that dataframe live? Like without a need to re-run, let's say some dashboard or smth that updates every 1 minute or whatever

Comment: Hi, can you provide the code you already have done?